# SG90 MIcro Servo Motor Push Button Arduino for Vending Machie Prototype

Tags: rotation, arduino

I have made my new code for my prototype again and my problems are:
When the arduino started running, the three SG90 Micro servo motors rotated 360 degrees at the same time and didn't stop. When I pushed the round push button it slowed the speed of rotation of the servo motor.

When I tried to simulate my program to 123d.circuits.io, it worked. I used the momentary push button since there is no round push button there.

What I wanted to achieve is that:

When push button A/B/C is pushed, the servo Motor A/B/C will rotate 360 deg to dispense an item for my vending machine prototype.

Here's my code. Hope you can help me.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int pushButtonA = 2;
const int pushButtonB = 4;
const int pushButtonC = 7;

Servo myservoA;
Servo myservoB;
Servo myservoC;

int pos = 0;
int buttonStateA = 0;
int buttonStateB = 0;
int buttonStateC = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButtonA, INPUT);
  pinMode(pushButtonB, INPUT);
  pinMode(pushButtonC, INPUT);

  myservoA.attach(3);
  myservoB.attach(5);
  myservoC.attach(9);
}

void loop() {

  buttonStateA = digitalRead (pushButtonA);
  buttonStateB = digitalRead (pushButtonB);
  buttonStateC = digitalRead (pushButtonC);

  if((buttonStateA == LOW) && (buttonStateB == HIGH) && (buttonStateC == HIGH)){
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++);
    myservoA.write(pos);
    delay(15);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  }
      if((buttonStateB == LOW) && (buttonStateA == HIGH) && (buttonStateC == HIGH)){
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++);
    myservoB.write(pos);
    delay(15);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  }
          if((buttonStateC == LOW) && (buttonStateB == HIGH) && (buttonStateA == HIGH)){
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++);
    myservoC.write(pos);
    delay(15);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  };
}
```

Comment: `for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++);` is equivalent to `pos = 361;`

Comment: so should it be pos <360?

Comment: I mean It should be problem that the `for` loops won't work as loop because they don't do any work except for incrementing `pos`.

Comment: Then should I make another code for this? Can you suggest a code? Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. As mentioned by @MikeCAT, the for loops in the code are empty because you added a semi-colon after them. See [Effect of semicolon after 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421395/effect-of-semicolon-after-for-loop) for further clarification.
2. There is no need to perform `digitalWrite` in servo pins. For controlling them just use the method `write` from the *Servo* class.

Corrected code:

```
 #include <Servo.h>

const int pushButtonA = 2;
const int pushButtonB = 4;
const int pushButtonC = 7;

Servo myservoA;
Servo myservoB;
Servo myservoC;

int pos = 0;
int buttonStateA = 0;
int buttonStateB = 0;
int buttonStateC = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButtonA, INPUT);
  pinMode(pushButtonB, INPUT);
  pinMode(pushButtonC, INPUT);

  myservoA.attach(3);
  myservoB.attach(5);
  myservoC.attach(9);
}

void loop() {

  buttonStateA = digitalRead (pushButtonA);
  buttonStateB = digitalRead (pushButtonB);
  buttonStateC = digitalRead (pushButtonC);

  if((buttonStateA == LOW) && (buttonStateB == HIGH) && (buttonStateC == HIGH)){
    for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++) {
       myservoA.write(pos);
       delay(15);
    }
  }

  if((buttonStateB == LOW) && (buttonStateA == HIGH) && (buttonStateC == HIGH)){
    for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++) {
       myservoB.write(pos);
       delay(15);
    }
  }

  if((buttonStateC == LOW) && (buttonStateB == HIGH) && (buttonStateA == HIGH)){
    for(pos = 0; pos <=360; pos++) {
       myservoC.write(pos);
       delay(15);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, are you sure the motors can rotate up to 360? Usually this kind of motor rotates between 0 and 180 degrees.

Comment: Yes i'm sure. We have modified the servo motor to rotate 360 deg. 
When I uploaded the new program, it just did the same thing. it rotated 360 deg at the same time non-stop. But I know that the code that you said is correct. I think it's now because of my wiring or because of the round push button?

Comment: Usually these motors rotate to 0 degrees when you turn on the power. If all motors rotated at the same time from zero to 360 then this behavior might be due your wiring since the code above allows only one motor to be rotating at the same time.