# Simple for loop not working in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to get my program to repeat the letter "a" 255 times, but for some reason this prints "a" just once and then stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    for(int e = 0; e < 253; e++);
    {
        printf("a");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon `;` after the for statement.

Comment: please see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421395/effect-of-semicolon-after-for-loop

Comment: `for(int e = 0; e < 253; e++);` --> `for(int e = 0; e < 255; e++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    for(int e = 0; e < 253; e++)
    {
            printf("a");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vote to close for typo. Questions like that don't need an answer.

Comment: @RSahu Okay. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a semicolon end of this loop **for(int e = 0; e < 253; e++);**. The for loop just runs without doing anything. Finally the rest of the statement gets executed and you get only one print.

Comment: Vote to close for typo. Questions like that don't need an answer.