# Why is there no output when I run my code?

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file called ecoli.txt, which contains the DNA sequence for ecoli, and store its contents into a string. I tried to print the string to test my code. However, when I run the program, there is no output. I am still new to java so I am sure there is an error in my code, I just need help finding it.

```
package codons;
import java.io.*;
public class codons 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            FileReader codons = new FileReader("codons.txt");
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("ecoli.txt");
            BufferedReader ecoli = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            StringBuilder dna_string = new StringBuilder();
            String line = ecoli.readLine();
            while(line != null);
            {
                dna_string.append(line);
                line = ecoli.readLine();
            }
            String string = new String(dna_string);
            System.out.println(string);
            ecoli.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

edit:

I was still having trouble getting the program to work the way I wanted it to so I attempted to complete writing the rest of what I wanted in the program and I am still not getting any output. Anyway, this is where I am at now:

```
package codons;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
public class codons 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            FileReader filecodons = new FileReader("codons.txt");
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("ecoli.txt");
            BufferedReader ecoli = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            StringBuilder dna_sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = ecoli.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                dna_sb.append(line);
                line = ecoli.readLine();
            }
            String dna_string = new String(dna_sb);
            ecoli.close();
            BufferedReader codons = new BufferedReader(filecodons);
            StringBuilder codon_sb = new StringBuilder();
            String codon = codons.readLine();
            while(codon != null)
            {
                codon_sb.append(codon);
                line = codons.readLine();
            }
            String codon_string = new String(codon_sb);
            codons.close();
            for(int x = 0; x <= codon_sb.length(); x++)
            {
                int count = 0;
                String codon_ss = new String(codon_string.substring(x, x+3));
                for(int i = 0; i <= dna_sb.length(); i++)
                {
                    String dna_ss = new String(dna_string.substring(i, i+3));
                    int result = codon_ss.compareTo(dna_ss);
                    if(result == 0)
                    {
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("The codon '");
                System.out.print(codon_ss);
                System.out.print("'is in the dna sequence");
                System.out.print(count);
                System.out.println("times.");
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Time to debug  -- print out the line within the while loop to see what is going on, print out the path to your file to be sure that it is correct

Comment: You should also add one more catch block for just `Exception` in case the exception type isn't `FileNotFoundException` or `IOException`.

Comment: I'm also perplexed as to why you're iterating over `line` when it's initialized as a `String`. There's really no point to that - better off being an `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: voting to close as a typographical/trivial error

Comment: @DrewKennedy I want to read multiple lines from the file to one long string. I used a while loop to append the line that was read when the string 'line' was initialized and then read the next line before appending again until there are no more lines.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I printed the line within the while loop and each line does output as it should but as the program continues, the lines disappear and there is eventually a blank screen again.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `;` after `while(line != null)`, it causes an infinite loop instead of executing the next instructions.

The reason is explained here: [Effect of semicolon after 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421395/effect-of-semicolon-after-for-loop) (the question is about the `C` language, but it is equivalent in `Java`).

Comment: I understand why the semicolon should be removed but there is still no output after I removed it.

Comment: @Nunzio the provided example with a test file works as expected, if you still don't see the output there could be a problem somewhere else or with the input file that you are using

Comment: I edited my post with an update of where I am now. I still don't have an output. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.