# Update statement in empty for loop

Tags: c++

A similar question has been answered here[https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421435/3276830 ]. The author says

> The following code

```
 for (i=0;i<5;i++);
 {
     printf("hello\n");
 }
```

> is interpreted as follows:
>
> - Repeat five times `for (i=0;i<5;i++)`
> - ... do nothing (semicolon)
> - Open a new scope for local variables `{`
> - ... Print "hello"
> - Close the scope `}`

However, for the following for loop

```
int i = 0;
for(;i++;cout<<i<<" ");
cout<<i<<" ";
```

The output I get is just `1`, but I expected it to be `123456.....`

**Edit**, I know the difference between prefix and postfix operation. But yeah I did miss that it was 0 the first time loop ran.

Comment: Your continue condition is `i++` which quickly evaluates to 0 which is falsey

Comment: Ah, I missed it! Thanks @NickA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I know the difference between prefix and postfix operation. But yeah I did miss that it was 0 the first time loop ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
for(;i++;cout<<i<<" ");
```

This loop can never execute because `i` is `0`, so `i++` evaluates to `0` (the value **before** incrementing it) which is *false*. Try `++i` instead.

Answer (score 1):

the

`for(;;i++, cout<<i<<" ");`

looks more **aesthetically** :) correct and will work no matter prefix or postfix