# What are the mistakes i did in the code. It is not giving any output?

Tags: c

What are the mistakes i did in the code ? It is not giving any output. The question is given in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELvnH.jpg). I am using the ASCII variable set to print the set of alphabet and digits .

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, temp, t, s, e;
    char test[20], start = 'a', end = 'z';
    scanf("%s", test);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(test) && (test[i] == '-'); i++);
    for (; i < strlen(test););
    {
        if (isalpha(test[i]) != 0)
        {
            start = test[i];
            for (; (i < strlen(test)) && (isdigit(test[i]) == 0); i++);
        }

        end = test[i - 1];
        temp = end - start + 1;

        if (isdigit(test[i]) != 0)
        {
            s = test[i];
            for (; (i < strlen(test)) && (isalpha(test[i]) == 0); i++);
        }

        e = test[i - 1];
        t = e - s + 1;

        for (j = 0; j < temp; ++j, start++)
        {
            printf("%c", start);
        }
        printf("\n");

        for (j = 0; j < t; ++j, s++)
        {
            printf("%c", s);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Text should be posted as text and not as a liked image. (That is missing words on the right side.)

Comment: You are ending the for loop with a semicolon. The rest of the bracket is not inside the loop `for (; i < strlen(test););` Also, do you want 2 for loops here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put a `;` at the end of `for` loops and that's the reason the body of the for `loop` is not being executed as expected.
[Effect of semicolon after 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421395/effect-of-semicolon-after-for-loop)

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(test) && (test[i] == '-'); i++);
for (; i < strlen(test););
for (; (i < strlen(test)) && (isdigit(test[i]) == 0); i++);
for (; (i < strlen(test)) && (isalpha(test[i]) == 0); i++);
```

Remove the `;` from the end of each `for` loop.

You should also remove the inner for loop as it has already mentioned in the outer `for` loop. **Please check the body of each `for` loop properly**.