# Var_dump shows 2 elements in array but foreach only show last element

Tags: php

So, I'm appending an array of objects to a `FormData` and sending the form with an `ajax` post request.

On my php page, I can access all form elements just fine (with the usual `$_POST['field_name']`), but when I try to access the array element I have appended, I'm having some problems.

Basically if I `var_dump` the element (called `$_POST['dynamic_form']`) I see an array of 2 (which is correct), but if I try to loop this array and echo the values only the last element of the array is echoed.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < form_elements.length; i++) {
    formData.append('dynamic_form[]', JSON.stringify(form_elements[i])); }
           //THIS IS MY AJAX REQUEST           
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'myurl',
    data:formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType:false,          
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        alert("form saved");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("request failed");
    } });//fine ajax

//HERE MY PHP $dynamic_form = $_POST['dynamic_form']; var_dump($dynamic_form);

foreach( $dynamic_form as $form ); {echo $form;}
```

the `var_dump` result in the console is correct:

> array(2) {   [0]=>   string(59) "{"type":"text","name":"","value":"2","label":"disponibile"}"   [1]=>  string(55) "{"type":"textarea","name":"","value":"1","label":"asd"}" }

but the `echo` inside the `foreach` loop only shows the last element of the array:

> {"type":"textarea","name":"","value":"1","label":"asd"}

`is_array($dynamic_form)`
returns true (correct)

`count($dynamic_form)`
returns 2 (correct)

I have tried a `for` loop instead of the `foreach` but I still have problems.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your `foreach` should not be working.

Comment: Remove `;` after `foreach`.

Comment: As soon as i posted the question i realized there was a ; in the foreach... i removed the semicolon and now it is working as expected. I'm so dumb sometimes... sorry and thank you! ( i have no idea why it was partially working with the semicolon and not raising an error or something)

Comment: [Topical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13421395/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it should be closed as a type, I will explain

```
foreach( $dynamic_form as $form ); {echo $form;}
```

is executed as

```
foreach( $dynamic_form as $form ) {
    // do nothing
} 
// echoes last value assigned to `$form` in loop.
{echo $form;}
```

And yes,

```
foreach( $dynamic_form as $form );
```

is **absolutely valid** code (though I don't know why you could need it unless it is a typo, as in question).

Comment: Modularity. All the looping constructs have basically the same structure, and they all allow an empty body.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo ( a really dumb one ). But at least i learnt something new! Ty

Comment: If answer helps - you can __accept__ and optionally upvote it. It will help other users and also increase your reputation.