# Confused with "for loop" output

Tags: c, linux, for-loop

I have a very basic C program, and confused with its output:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
        int i;
        char s[] = "K";

        for(i=0; s[i]; i++); {
                printf("%d ", i);
                printf("%c ", s[i]);
        }
}
```

It outputs i value as 1, but as per one of the answer from this thread:
[Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop)

```
    int i = 0; // Initialization

    loopStart:
    if (i < 5) // Condition
    {
       Output(i);

       i++ or ++i; // Increment

       goto loopStart;
     }
```

Increment happens after the Output(i) (equivalent to printf("%d ", i);), Then how i's value comes as 1 but not 0?

Comment: What is Output?

Comment: I think, I overlooked the semicolon but it actually lead me to see this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421395/effect-of-semicolon-after-for-loop, to get clear idea, what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `;` after for loop

```
for(i=0; s[i]; i++);
```

Remove semicolon and it's fine.

```
for(i=0; s[i]; i++)
```

It's because the semicolon will be considered as an end of the statement and your `printf` is not part of the loop and will be executed once the loop execution gets completed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code block

```
for(i=0; s[i]; i++); {
    printf("%d ", i);
    printf("%c ", s[i]);
}
```

has misleading indentation. With correct indentation, it would look like this:

```
for(i=0; s[i]; i++)
    ;

{
    printf("%d ", i);
    printf("%c ", s[i]);
}
```

As you can see, the `for` loop is empty, and the code block with the `printf` statements is not part of the `for` statement (which means that it is not part of the loop). What you want is probably the following:

```
for(i=0; s[i]; i++) {
    printf("%d ", i);
    printf("%c ", s[i]);
}
```

Note that this code is identical to your code, except that a semicolon was removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you add semicolon at the end of for loop then execution will terminated after checking the condition in for loop.
If you want the output : 0
And                                :  K

Then try this

```
int main()
{
     int i = 0;
     char s[] = 'K';
     for(i = 0; s[]; i++)
     {
          printf("%d", i);
          printf("%c",s[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```